# Server cannot access local files with information gathered from database

Tags: php

On my php file, I have this code

```
<img src="<?php echo $user['profile_pic']?>; " alt="">
```

The user variable has the array that is associated with the user row on mysql. And I am trying to access the profile pic column from that which is of type varchar that has the link to access the image stored in my local machine. When I run this code, I get the error given below

```
GET http://localhost/Demo/assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_carrot.png; 404 (Not Found)
```

But when I run the exact same code but instead of getting the data from the database I hardcode the path, the link works fine. Only when try to gather the data from database does the error appear. What am I doing wrong here? I have doubled checked the image link associated with the user in my database. Everything is fine, but the error appears for some reason.

The code I've provided below is the exact same string that is stored in the database as the user's profile picture

```
assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_carrot.png
```

Comment: What is the value that is stored in the DB?

Comment: try removing the ';' (semicolon) form the source tag since that is outside your echo tag and so it leads to the error message since the ';' is appended to the URI

Comment: I exclaim at my stupidity. Thanks @j4g0

Comment: yeah, happens to all of us :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems the semicolon outside of the php tag was the culprit. It works fine now. Thanks to @j4g0